# operands of = have illegal types

Tags: c, pointers, char, strdup

I am very new to C (after many years).  I am using lcc64 and have the following statement

```
char *logMessage = strdup(argv[1]);
```

I have no idea why I get the error

```
"operands of = have illegal types 'pointer to char' and 'int"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have `#include <string.h>`?

Comment: `strdup` is a non-standard extension. You need to have `#include <string.h>` *and* you need to ensure that `strdup` is visible. For gcc, you can do the latter by *not* using `-std=cNN`, where `NN` is `90`, `99`, or `11` to specify a version of the C standard.

Comment: strdup() dates back to the start of the C language, and all C libraries have it.  That makes it as much a standard as anything ratified by an organization.

Comment: You can also make it visible by putting `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` or `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500` before `#include <string.h>`, if you want to keep a `-std=c99` flag.

Answer (score 4):

you need to include `<string.h>` to declare strdup() as returning char*, else the compiler thinks it returns an int

Comment: Don't declare `strdup` yourself.

Comment: oops, I had `<string.h>` in there but it looks too much like a tag, and markdown swallowed it